# How can I set and get cookies (server side) in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I set and get cookies (server side) in Meteor?

Comment: @zengr: I think you misunderstood the question. Feel free to remove your comment and I'll remove this one too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Meteor does not currently have a supported way to use cookies on the server.

You can use cookies on the client, though. Here's a snippet to show a splash screen the first time the user visits a page:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (!document.cookie.match("splash="))      
      $('body').append(Meteor.ui.render(Template.splash));      
});

Template.splash.events = {
    'click .submit': function () {      
        document.cookie = "splash=ack;expires=Sat, 23 Mar 2013 00:00:0 GMT";    
        $('#splash_outer').remove();        
    }   
};
```

You could use a similar approach and set the cookies in client side code, then send the results to the server in a method call.

Comment: I need to get at a client cookie that is not bound to the current domain (so it needs to be accessible server side). [I've posted a follow-up here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/xLGOcruZ4c4/s2YnI4ZOkMIJ).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we got a solution: ostrio/cookies which work both on the server side and on the client side: https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/cookies

```
import { Cookies } from 'meteor/ostrio:cookies';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const oldValue = cookies.get("key");
cookies.set("key", "newValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

April 2014 update: You can use [meteor-user-session](https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-user-session) now.